# AE + Photoshop| How to do phone numbers increasing effect? [Details Inside]

Tags: after-effects

Hello Okay so i need help I will show you some videos and I'd love to get an answer on exactly how they got made?

As you can see, There's someone who shoot himself playing the game on a smartphone.

Then he opened a game hack generator website that gave him more gold and gems to his game.

Then he came back to the game and as you can see the gold and gems started to increase until they reach 999,999 each one of them.

So how did the makers of the videos did the effect of the numbers getting increase?

When I asked a few people how they done that they said that they won't tell me but they did say that they edit the video with After Effect+Photoshop.

I really want to know how they did the number increasing in mobile game effect.
Thanks in advance :)

Comment: That's almost 18 minutes of footage to watch. I don't think people on this site will spend 18 minutes to answer your question. For each video, will you please indicate where the effect appears?

Comment: I scrolled to the end of the first video, and it's in the last 30 seconds or so. Didn't watch any of the others.

Answer (score 0):

Two ways you could do it. First, get a screen capture of you playing the game, edit it and replace the numbers, and finally make a movie of the result. Play the movie full screen and mime pressing the buttons. This would be easier technically, but would require some "thumb acting".

Second, do a motion track of the phone screen. Create a movie of the increasing numbers and add it as a tracked 3D layer, aligned to the phone's screen. This would be a reasonably difficult exercise in compositing, given that as well as matching the movement you would have to roto or matte out the fingers if they go in front of the numbers, and you'd also have to match the drifting autofocus of the recording camera and the reflections on the screen and moire that the original screen exhibits to get it perfectly right. I'd budget a week for it if you want it photoreal for HD.